# Dystopian story about a Man searching for his son in a camp for people with an illness

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to identify a story I read about 15+ years ago.

The main premise of the story is that a super strain of the Aids Virus has become prevalent and possibly air born, or at least very easily transmitted, and is lethal far quicker as a result anyone that has caught it, or is at risk, are rounded up and placed in camps which the government claim are designed to help find a cure and look after infected.

The main protagonist has faked having the disease in order to find his son in one of these camps, I think he is a reporter but might be wrong about that. He infiltrates the camp and during the course of finding out what is really going on he realises that once the camp is full it will be destroyed by missile and firestorm killing everyone in it, rather then, as stated by the government people being allowed a dignified death.

Comment: This has similarities to [_The Power of Five_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Five) series, note the section with Matt and Lohan in the jungle. However, there are enough differences that it doesn't seem worthy of an answer.

Comment: A fair bit of commonality with the movie "Outbreak", though that was a decade earlier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like [The Immortals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Immortals_(Hickman_novel)) by Tracy Hickman (more known for producing fantasy novels with frequent collaborator Margaret Weis).

The Wikipedia summary hits most of the notes you mentioned:

> When a cure for AIDS turns out to be more virulent than the disease, the U.S. establishes quarantine camps in the desert southwest. Michael Barris, a TV producer, masquerades as one of the infected and travels to the camps in search of his son. He finds horrific conditions, and learns that the so-called quarantine camps are death camps where the infected are gathered, purposefully brutalized, and ultimately cremated alive, their ashes bulldozed into the desert sand. Barris's son escapes the camp before the cycle of immolation, carrying the evidence he needs to expose the governmental mis-information campaign.

Comment: That's the one, thanks :)